# Sequence Tending to Infinity, application of the formal definition.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis, definition, recreational-mathematics

I understand the formal definition for a sequence tending to infinity is:

$$\forall A \gt 0, \quad \exists \, N \in \mathbb{N} \quad such \, that \, \, a_n \gt A, \quad \forall n \gt N. $$

In regards to the part of the definition; $ a_n \gt A, \quad \forall n \gt N$,
does that mean that for a certain $N$, $a_N \gt A$, and all values after $N$, hence $n \gt N$ it occurs that, $a_n \gt A$?

There is just one small query I have in applying the definition, using it to prove a trivial sequence:

Prove:$$ a_n =\sqrt n \to\, infinity.$$

Proof: $$Let \quad A \gt 0 \quad be\,\, given.$$

Then, $$\sqrt n \gt A \implies\, n \gt A^2.$$

Intuitively I understand that $N \in \mathbb{N}$ would be chosen so that it is greater than or equal to $A^2$.

But using the above statement:

If $$N=A^2, \,then \, n \gt N \, is \, true.$$

But if $N \gt A^2,$ then could it not occur that $N \gt n$?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. But for a given $A$, you let $N$ be such that $N=A^2+1$. Then you have $\sqrt{N} = \sqrt{A^2+1}>A$. Also, when $n>N$, you have $\sqrt{n}>\sqrt{N}= \sqrt{A^2+1}>A$.

Comment: @Misakov my questions are both the last statement and the paragraph 'in regards to...'.,if that makes sense? I'm not very good at understanding things, sorry.

Comment: That part translates to "for any $n$ such that $n>N, a_n >A$".

Comment: @Misakov okay cool, thanks.